# User Password is not Encrypted Django with Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, password-encryption, django-serializer

When I create a user password remains in plain text. Also Im using signals to create user profiles related to users. Though I use the set_password method passwords are not encrypting.

Serializer.py

```
class UserSerializerAPI(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password','is_teacher']
        extra_kwargs = {"password":{"write_only":True}}

        def create(self,validated_data):
            username = validated_data['username']
            email = validated_data['email']
            password = validated_data['password']
            user_obj = User(
                username = username,
                email = email
            )
            user_obj.set_password(password)
            user_obj.save()
            return user_obj
```

views.py

```
class createuser(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializerAPI
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
```

Comment: Are the passwords also not encrypted in the database, or are you only seeing them unencrypted in the response of the API call? Serializers in CreateAPIView will respond with the raw data that has been submitted, not what is stored in the database.

Comment: In django admin it shows in plain text and its not giving me the error "invalid password".

Comment: I use the AbstractUser to extend the user model. After creating the superuser it django admin allows me to change the hash for the admin users. But for normal users I cant see any hash and I also can change the password

Comment: After adding UserAdmin to the admin.py passwords are not showing in plain text. Now it's saying invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm for users created with the serializer

Comment: @NavanjaneVidunuwanKindelpiti where do you calling the `user_obj`? can you please show us your full code of  `UserSerializerAPI` ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort Finally I solved that using perform_create method in Registration View

Answer (score 2):

you can code like this`

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('username', 'email', 'password','password1',  'is_teacher',)

      def validate(self, attr):
        validate_password(attr['password'])
        return attr

      def create(self, validated_data):
          user = User.objects.create( # this line  will solve your problem
              username=validated_data['username'],
              is_teacher=validated_data['user_type'],
              email=validated_data['email'],
            )
          user.set_password(validated_data['password']) 
          user.save()



          return user
```

Best Regards